# How to end an infinite loop on a cloud server?

Tags: bash, boot, cloud

Today I was answering a question here about an infinite loop between

`/etc/profile` and `/etc/bash/bashrc` (or any other variant from bash initial script)

where the first call the second and vice-versa. Leaving you incapable of entering commands in bash.

On that specific scenario the solution was to boot from a live system and edit one of both files... but what could someone do if, for example, the same happens on an AWS instance?

This is a **theoretical** question, I suppose that it could happen to someone.

PS. I know that the fastest solution would be to kill the server and start a new one, but is there any other option?

Comment: It was `/etc/bash.bashrc` not `/etc/bash/bashrc`, but thanks for your answer (will wait about 24 hours before accepting you answer for a secret reason)

Comment: Kill the server and start a new one.

Comment: @JohnMiliter no problem :) I hope it can solve the problem, at least that's what I'd do in that case, btw on my gentoo I have a `/etc/bash/bashrc` script that calls for several other, that's why my second path :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case (I assume that is the same with all the IaaS providers), is possible to attach an existing volume to a different instance.

From [Amazon's official docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-attaching-volume.html)

> Prerequisites
>
> - Determine the device names that you'll use. For more information, see Device Naming on Linux Instances.
> - Determine how many volumes you can attach to your instance. For more information, see Instance Volume Limits.
> - If a volume is encrypted, it can only be attached to an instance that supports Amazon EBS encryption. For more information, see Supported Instance Types.
> - If a volume has an AWS Marketplace product code:
>
>   - The volume can only be attached to a stopped instance.
>   - You must be subscribed to the AWS Marketplace code that is on the volume.
>   - The configuration (instance type, operating system) of the instance must support that specific AWS Marketplace code. For example, you cannot take a volume from a Windows instance and attach it to a Linux instance.
>   - AWS Marketplace product codes are copied from the volume to the instance.

After that is the same procedure as any physical server.